# Why I can't use object keys as variables on karma config file?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

To avoid duplicate the info about directories, I have create a set of variables to reuse in the config object. But, for some reason, Karma doesn't accept variable as an object key.
Why the keys "[templates]" and "[scripts]" break my karma.config?

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var root = 'public/src/';
  var templates = root + '**/*.html';

  config.set({

    preprocessors : {
      [templates] : 'ng-html2js'
    }

  }

}
```

As you can see, I am just showing the part of file I am interested in and to become easier (for you) to understand my question.
The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
[templates] : 'ng-html2js',
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Comment: [Computed properties within object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) are new with ECMAScript 6.

Comment: I don't understand why it is a exclusive feature of ES6. I have tried to make it on fiddle using pure JS and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsf8c319/

Comment: So your browser supports it

Comment: Feature implementation isn't automatic or global. Many of the most prominent engines do support the syntax, but maybe only in recent versions. Your browser is likely as up-to-date as possible. For Karma, Node v4 [supports many ES6 features](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) by default. However, if you're using an older version of Node and the V8 engine behind it, you can only use the features that were available at the time of its release.